# After upgrading to 22.04 from 20.04 I cannot update gcc

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, 22.04

I did an OTA update to 22.04.1 today. After performing numerous `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` I am stuck with the following packages that are not upgradeable:

```shell
sudo apt list --upgradeable
sudo apt list --upgradable   
Creating list.. done
gcc-10-base/jammy 10.3.0-15ubuntu1 amd64 [αναβαθμίσιμο από: 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04]
gcc-10-base/jammy 10.3.0-15ubuntu1 i386 [αναβαθμίσιμο από: 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04]
```

They say that are from an older package of 20.04. But when trying `sudo apt full-upgrade` they do not get updated. How can I remove them and clean up my system?

Answer (score 2):

Running `sudo apt install --only-upgrade gcc-10-base` did the trick. It updated gcc and removed the i386 package.